# looping through array to get data using eloquent inside eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm programming a tourism agency website. I've `hotels` in database which have a column called `stars` which is an integer its value is between 1 to 5.

I have a form which the user can search hotels based on their `stars`. The field is `checkbox` so he can search `five stars` and `four stars` hotels together for example.

I read the `stars array` and redirect the visitor to the search page using this code:

```
$stars_param = "";
    $i = 1;
    foreach($stars as $star){
        if($i == 1){
            $stars_param .= $star; 
        }else{
            $stars_param .= "&".$star;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $parameters = "filter=true&&stars=".$stars_param."&&price=".$price."&&area=".$area;
    return \Redirect::to('/hotels-search/?'.$parameters);
```

So the url will be like this:

```
hotels-search?filter=true&&stars=5&1&&price=300&&area=taksim
```

And in the `hotels-search` page I read the `$_GET` , and explode the stars variable and coded this query to fetch data:

```
$stars = $_GET['stars'];
$stars_array = explode('&', $stars);
$price = $_GET['price'];
$area = $_GET['area'];
$this['hotels'] = \Lilessam\Hotels\Models\Hotel::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where(function($query) use($stars_array){
                $i = 1;
                foreach($stars_array as $star){
                    if($i == 1){
                        $query->where('stars', $star);
                    }else{
                        $query->orWhere('stars', $star);
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

                })->where('price', '<=', $price)->whereHas('area', function($query) use($area){
                                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $area);
                                })->paginate(5);
```

But with this if I search hotels with 5 and 1 stars, I only get the five stars hotels!

if I search hotels with 4 and 3 stars, I only get the four stars hotels ! Other times I get nothing from database at all !!

How can I make a query so I can get hotels with 1 or 3 or 5 stars at the same time?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don' you use this

```
$this['hotels'] = \Lilessam\Hotels\Models\Hotel::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->whereIn('start',$stars_array)
                    ->where('price', '<=', $price)
                    ->whereHas('area', function($query) use($area){
                            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $area);
                            })->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

get variables are separated by single `&`, not `&&`. every name value pair has the form:- name=value.

Try this.

```
$stars_param = implode(",",$stars);
$parameters = "filter=true&stars=".$stars_param."&price=".$price."&area=".$area;
    return \Redirect::to('/hotels-search/?'.$parameters);
```

Then your URL will be:

```
hotels-search?filter=true&stars=5,1&price=300&area=taksim
```

And in the hotel search page

```
$stars = $_GET['stars'];
$stars_array = explode(',', $stars);
$price = $_GET['price'];
$area = $_GET['area'];
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Actually I was separating them with only one `&` It's been resolved when I used `whereIn`